# Sharepoint Doc Lib Content Types

Tags: sharepoint-2007, workflow, document-library

So I would like it when a user creates a new folder in my sharepoint document library that 4 template documents also get added inside the new folder.  I get that the user could just click on the document template for each template individual but I want them added all the time.

There doesn't seem to be an option to add template documents to a document lib folder content type.

Sooo.... Is my only alternative to create a custom sharepoint workflow that checks for the folder creation inside my doc lib. (Ideally maybe restricting it to only when a specific folder of my custom content type is created.. )  This seems like a simple workflow to create but I want to make sure that I even need to create one since I haven't actually created a custom sharepoint workflow yet...

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right; there's no built-in functionality for this. It should be reasonable simple to write a workflow that runs when something is added to a library, checks to see if it is a folder, and adds the items into the folder. It would probably be easiest to have the template documents in another folder somewhere, and then copy them over.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I found this example that helped out a lot:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/MOSS_FolderContentTypeWF.aspx